# Why the complex syntax gives error?

Tags: php

Look at the code below:

```
<?php
//The array stores the nodes of a blog entry
$entry = array('title' => "My First Blog Entry",
        'author' => "daNullSet",
        'date' => "August 10, 2012",
        'body' => "This is the bosy of the blog");
echo "The title of the blog entry is ".{$entry['title']};
?>
```

It gives the following error with me.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php-blog\simple-blog\array-test.php on line 7

The error goes away if I remove curly brackets introducing the complex syntax in echo statement in the code above. Help me to debug the code above please.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the curly braces and it will work fine. This behavior is not a bug, but rather, your syntax is incorrect. In short, using curly braces for complex variable interpolation works within double quotes or in a heredoc, not outside.

More detailed explanation:

Use this:

```
echo "The title of the blog entry is ".$entry['title'];
```

Complex variables (and interpolation of expressions inside curly braces) specifically work WITHIN double quoted strings or heredocs, where correct interpolation is required, and where ambiguity could occur. This is a piece of clean syntax, and therefore causes no ambiguity, which means no disambiguation is required.

Check out more on complex variables here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

If you were enclosing the array value inside the double quotes, you can use the curly braces to allow for correct variable interpolation. However, this works just fine and most people should be able to read this perfectly and understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

you are using  `{` wrong way

use
either

```
 echo "The title of the blog entry is ".$entry['title'];
```

OR

```
 echo "The title of the blog entry is ". $entry{title};
```

even you need to concatenate the string. you can write everything inside `""`

```
  echo "The title of the blog entry is $entry{title}";
```

**[Working DEMO](http://codepad.org/caqK09df)**

Read [`Complex (curly) syntax`](https://www.php.net/language.types.string.php)

Comment: I did not down vote you but apparently your second code would generate  `Notice: Use of undefined constant title - assumed 'title' in`

Comment: yea well this one got a couple down votes, not just one a COUPLE

Comment: I think the curly braces in the second and third example are causing the "title" to be treated as a whole new variable, not an array key. And since you do not have a "$" right before "title", it shows an undefined constant notice.

Comment: Well, you learn something new each day...
Although, the last one writes Array{title}, but if you put another set of braces around it {$entry{title}}, then it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "The title of the blog entry is " . $entry['title'];
```

Answer (score 1):

i think the correct syntax you want to use  is something like this

```
echo "The title of the blog entry is {$entry['title']}";
```

Answer (score 1):

The right way to you use `}` is :

```
echo "The title of the blog entry is  {$entry['title']}";
```

You can as well just use :

```
echo "The title of the blog entry is " . $entry['title'];
```